# stream a JSC format file in browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I have to stream a JSC format file in browser using javascript. Please let me help .. how can i do this. or please suggest me any source to learn about the same.

this JSC file contains audio and that piece of data I have to stream in player. So I want to know how we can parse given file and stream on the same.

it has 3 parts. one is length(number of total chars of header and data), second is header and third is data. and seperated by | sign.
e.g. 000012|header|solve

Comment: Please add more details or show what research you have already done

Comment: file also contains audio content. I have to play that content.